# Custom dialog and Builder dialog have different themes

Tags: android, user-interface, android-dialog, android-theme

For most of my Android app's dialogs I use Builder's built-in methods, such as setSingleChoiceItems, but I need 2-3 dialogs that are custom AlertDialogs using my own views.

The custom dialogs look very different from the ready-made ones (text size, background etc).

How can I make my custom dialogs look like the Builder ones?
I have not specified any theme for any of the dialogs.

I created this one using an AlertDialog.Builder with the setSingleChoiceItems(...) method.

[image: Created using AlertDialog.Builder]

This one was created using builder.setView(layout).

[image: Created using a View]

Comment: Can you add pictures as to the differences between the two? Your activity theme may be different to the one the Builder is using.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. By "custom AlertDialogs", do you mean you subclassed `AlertDialog`? `Builder` is an inner class of `AlertDialog`, so the way you phrase some things are confusing in that context.

Comment: Added screen-shots as well as some more explanation, I hope this makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom view with **setView**, but I recommend to use DialogFragment, in DialogFragment you can use any **View** and just View event handlers like onClickListener etc.

Comment: I am using setView, but the theme used is different from the one used by Builder's setSingleChoiceItems(...)

Answer (score 0):

try out this

set custom theme in dialog to set background and no title of dialog as below

```
<style name="ActivityDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">      
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background_image</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>      
    </style>
```

and make a layout of UI

```
protected void createDialog() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.ActivityDialog);//this take context and style parameter

             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogUI); // here load coustom UI layout 



             Button okbtn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
             Button cancelbtn = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.rep_cancel_Button);
             okbtn .setOnClickListener(okClickListener);
             cancelbtn .setOnClickListener(cancelClickListener);

             dialog.show();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a custom theme, I want the same theme used by Builder's built-in methods.